# How do I Auto Re-tweet Somebody or a Hashtag And Follow Them Using Tweetinvi

Tags: tweetinvi

I want to make a automatic re-tweet/follow bot so I can follow and re-tweet  certain people and RT a specific hashtag (#Giveaways) I am using Tweetinvi but I dont understand how to do these things I've listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi.

You could simply do the following:

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");

var fs = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
fs.AddTrack("#fnqifqun");

fs.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
    var tweet = args.Tweet;
    tweet.PublishRetweetAsync();
};

fs.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
```

Your bot is now complete!